# Suppress square brackets in input names generated by simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, simple-form

I'm working on a bookmarkable search form - with simple_form in order to get access to some custom inputs. Since no real model object is connected, I use the `:q` symbol to fake one:

```
= simple_form_for :q, url: projects_path, method: :get do |f|
  = f.input :area_id,
    as: :select,
    collection: (...)
  = f.input :description,
    as: :geocomplete
```

While this works, the naming conventions produce in not so nice URLs such as:

```
...?q[area_id]=16&q[description]=Paris&q[lng]=4.123&q[lat]=30.123
```

Is there a way to tell simple_form to suppress the fake `:q` object and produce URLs like:

```
...?area_id=16&description=Paris&lng=4.123&lat=30.123
```

Thanks for your hints!

Comment: That's still a valid params list. The controller should be recieving something like `q=>{area_id=>16, description=>'Paris'...}` which is still plenty usable. Is there a reason you want to clean up the URL?

Comment: Don't think this is possible, but with a so specific requirement, maybe you'll be better just using Rails standard helpers?

Comment: As I said, it works. And the controller end is no problem at all. But since we're building semantic URLs for other search parameters, I'd like to get rid of the square brackets in the URL.

Comment: I don't think you can remove the brackets as long as you're using a form of any kind. Rails automatically turns any form into a hash which is where the brackets come from. If you wanted to build the params without a form you could probably use things like `text_field_tag` that would get you the URL formatting that you want but it would no longer be within a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Martin wrote, it can't be done. So it's either standard form helpers or accept the square brackets. I've chosen the latter.